# ZeroMQ Message Size Length Limit?

Tags: zeromq, pyzmq

Suppose that several machines are interacting together using `python's` zeroMQ client.

These messages are naturally formatted as strings.

Is there a limit to the length of a message (string)?

Comment: I added my 2 cents below.  Let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is no limit to the size of messages being sent however small messages are handled differently than large messages (see [here](http://api.zeromq.org/master:zmq-msg-init-size)).

The max size of a small messages is defined in the source code at 30 bytes (see [here](https://github.com/zeromq/zeromq2-1/blob/master/include/zmq.h), look for ZMQ_MAX_VSM_SIZE).

Comment: Clearly you never have tried to send something larger than 2^31 :)

Comment: ZMQ_MAXMSGSIZE is an int64, so 2ˆ63 is more likely the limit

Comment: They increased the size limit. :) It is now 33 bytes for 64bit and 37 bytes for 32bit platforms. https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/blob/master/src/msg.hpp#L137

Answer (score 5):

There is the [socket option](http://api.zeromq.org/4-0:zmq-setsockopt) ZMQ_MAXMSGSIZE which causes a peer sending an oversized message to be disconnected, but the default is "no limit".

Comment: Does not answer the question.

Comment: @meawoppl `but the default is "no limit"` does answer the question!  IMHO this here is currently the most helpful answer (if you do not look in the comments of the accepted answer).

Answer (score 2):

No limit

As for small size messages transmitted within zmq_msg_t structures, their limit is 29 bytes (for zmq version 3.2.2)

"max_vsm_size = 29," quoted from https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/blob/master/src/msg.hpp

Answer (score 2):

Some socket types support up to 2^64, but some less than 2^31.

You should build a protocol that keeps chunks below that size anyway, but this is the real answer.

https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/issues/1332